# How to display calendar view in a single row in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, calendar

i don't know how to customize a calendar view to be the same as the picture for my application. Here is my example picture.

[image]

Comment: There is no way . You need to build it .make use of Recycler view .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the past, I had the same problem so I have created a Kotlin library which solves this problem. You can create a calendar with your custom UI and use selection features with few lines of code. You can [find the repository here](https://github.com/miso01/SingleRowCalendar) and [here is an article about my sample app](https://medium.com/@misosvec01/single-row-horizontal-calendar-has-never-been-easier-6ad989fafee8).

Additionally, [there is a similar library for Java here](https://github.com/TechIsFun/OneLineCalendar).

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can define a custom calender view like that. Here is my suggestion:

- ListView/ReceyclerView
- Calendar class

Easy way is make user pick month/year first, your list only display day.